# Change Bootstrap Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, styles

It is possible to change the whole size of bootstrap. I mean, not only the font size.

My webpage is shown too big, and it looks better with the Firefox windows at 80%-90%. It is this possible?

I suposse if I change the font size, buttons, boxes, containers, panels still looks the same size...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css transform to do it.

```
body {
   transform: scale(0.8);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   // add prefixed versions too.
}
```

It might cause some weird clipping and overflow issues but short of using a CSS preprocessor for bootstrap this is likely your best option.

Comment: This doesn't work fine because content doesn't not fill the whole windows. What I need is reduce the font and div size, but the content fill all the windows.

Comment: Have you tried applying the styles to your container div (the one wrapping the content you need resized)?

Comment: I should rezise all whole objects in the page... text, div, panel, tittle size, accordion... this is because I want to change the whole bootstrap :(

Comment: body {
   -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
   zoom: 0.8;
   zoom: 80%;
}

maybe try this